# Implementing ArcPy Describe function into file dictionary

Tags: arcpy, dictionary, describe-object

I'm currently using Python to create a dictionary when given a user input argument, collects the file data types and names in the dictionary determined by the ArcPy Describe function, so the output will look something like:

```
[u'Shapefile': ['a.shp', 'b.shp'] u'Raster: ['c.jpg,', 'd.jpg']
```

My code below prints items and their describe and their so I have right now:

> 'a.shp': <geoprocessing describe data object object at 0x06GH998>}

```
import arcpy, os, sys
inputDirectory = sys.argv[1]
files = os.listdir(inputDirectory)
fDictionary= {}

for f in files:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(os.path.join(f, inputDirectory))
    if f not in fDictionary:
        fDictionary[f] = desc
    else:
        fDictionary[f].append(desc)
print 'fDictionary {0}'.format(fDictionary)
```

I understand getting the object data type, I will need to use dot notation to add the `describe` object property to describe ([in order to bring out the `dataType`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/describe-object-properties.htm)) and possibly another for statement, but I'm not sure how to implement it in the loop.

Comment: You can use the `hasattr` and `getattr` built-in functions of Python to dynamically explore the properties of a `geoprocessing describe data object`

Answer (score 2):

You linked to a ArcGIS Pro help page (Python 3.6+) but you use a Python 2.7 `print` command. The code below is written in Python 3.6+.

In case you are using Python 2.7 with ArcGIS for Desktop which I don't have, you should still be able to run the scripts below but need to change the `print` command. See [What's new in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function). The rest *should* be interchangeable but I did not test it.

---

You have a few issues in your code:

1. `os.path.join(f, inputDirectory)` should be `os.path.join(inputDirectory, f)`.
2. You need to use [`desc.dataType`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/describe-object-properties.htm) to retrieve the data type and [`desc.file`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/describe-object-properties.htm) for the file name.
3. If the data type is not already in the dictionary, you'll need to assign a list, and not assigning the `desc` object.

```py
import os
import arcpy

inputDirectory = "D:\projects\playground\python\stackgis\data"  # simulating input

files = os.listdir(inputDirectory)

fDictionary = {}

for f in files:

    desc = arcpy.Describe(os.path.join(inputDirectory, f))
    
    if desc.dataType not in fDictionary:
        fDictionary[desc.dataType] = [desc.file]
    else:
        fDictionary[desc.dataType].append(desc.file)

print('fDictionary {0}'.format(fDictionary))
```

Output:

```
fDictionary {'ShapeFile': ['a.dbf', 'a.shp', 'b.dbf', 'b.shp'], 'File': ['a.prj', 'a.shx', 'b.prj', 'b.shx'], 'RasterDataset': ['c.jpg', 'd.jpg']}
```

---

**In addition**, if you only want to process datasets, you may want to consider using [`arcpy.da.Walk`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/walk.htm) (but also iterates through sub directories) or [`arcpy.ListFeatureClasses`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listfeatureclasses.htm) (requires `arcpy.env.workspace` to be set) to iterate over the datasets. The example below uses `arcpy.da.Walk`:

```py
import os
import arcpy

inputDirectory = "D:\projects\playground\python\stackgis\data"  # simulating input

fDictionary = {}

for root, _, datasets in arcpy.da.Walk(inputDirectory):

    for dataset in datasets:
        
        desc = arcpy.Describe(os.path.join(root, dataset))
        
        if desc.dataType not in fDictionary:
            fDictionary[desc.dataType] = [desc.file]
        else:
            fDictionary[desc.dataType].append(desc.file)

print('fDictionary {0}'.format(fDictionary))
```

Output:

```
fDictionary {'ShapeFile': ['a.shp', 'b.shp'], 'RasterDataset': ['c.jpg', 'd.jpg']}
```

---

You could use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make your code simpler:

```py
import os
import arcpy

from collections import defaultdict

input_folder = "D:\projects\playground\python\stackgis\data"  # simulating input

output = defaultdict(list)

for root, _, datasets in arcpy.da.Walk(input_folder):

    for dataset in datasets:
        
        desc = arcpy.Describe(os.path.join(root, dataset))
        output[desc.dataType].append(desc.file)

print(f"Output {output}")
```

Output:

```
Output {'ShapeFile': ['a.shp', 'b.shp'], 'RasterDataset': ['c.jpg', 'd.jpg']}
```

---

**Addendum:** According to Vince's comment you may be looking to get the `dataType` and `file` properties dynamically from the `Describe` object. There would be no need to do that. Both properties are *always present* in any `Describe` object.

> All data, regardless of the data type, will always acquire the generic [Describe Object](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/functions/describe-object-properties.htm) properties.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/describe.htm

However, it makes sense to check for properties which are not available for all data types. See Vince's comments where he suggest [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) and [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

Here is an example with the property [`extent`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/dataset-properties.htm) which is not be available for all data types:

```py
desc = arcpy.Describe(r"d:\data\a.shp")
if hasattr(desc, "extent"):
    extent = getattr(desc, "extent")
```

However, you are accessing only generic properties. Therefore is no need using `hasattr` and `getattr`.

Comment: I was expecting an answer that addressed the concern of dynamically getting properties out of a Describe object (via `hasattr` and `getattr`).  All the properties you have here are hard-coded, so this seems to answer a different Question.

Comment: The OP has an expected and an actual output which doesn't match. They also write "[...] but I'm not sure how to implement it in the loop." This answer does address their code issues. I don't read any concerns of dynamically getting properties but I am also not native in English, so maybe I am wrong.